# Why i need to click twice to call my function

Tags: javascript

i need your help please, my function works but i need to click twice to call it. i tried a lot of options but never works fine (sorry for my english im french)

```js
function deleteItem() {
  let products = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteItem");
  for (let product of products) {
    product.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let id = e.target.getAttribute("dataid");
      let color = e.target.getAttribute("datacolor");
      let deleteItem = basket.find(
        (element) => element.id == id && element.color == color
      );
      console.log(deleteItem);
      basket = basket.filter((item) => item != deleteItem);
      localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(basket)),
        (window.location.href = "cart.html");
    });
  }
}
deleteItem();
```

```html
<div class="cart__item__content__settings__delete">
          <p class="deleteItem" onclick="deleteItem()" dataid="${id}" datacolor="${color}">Supprimer</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: with the first click, you call the function that creates the eventListener which gets called on the second click

Comment: @Psi For sake of argument .. OP has called `deleteItem();`  directly after the function.  --  Should that not create the listener?

Comment: @Zak you’re right, it should. But the fact that it doesn’t work led me to believe that he didn’t call the function in the live code

Answer (score 1):

Testing your code, it works on first click.

dont use onclick and eventlistener together, as you will be capturing multiple clicks

This is not an answer, but working code.

```js
function deleteItem() {
  let products = document.querySelectorAll(".deleteItem");
  for (let product of products) {
    product.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let id = e.target.getAttribute("dataid");
      let color = e.target.getAttribute("datacolor");
      alert("i am clicked")
    });
  }
}
deleteItem();
```

```html
<div class="cart__item__content__settings__delete">
          <p class="deleteItem"  dataid="5" datacolor="blue">Supprimer</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: up for the advice not to combine onclick and addEventListener